# In TextField( ) why we use " onSubmitted : " syntax?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, flutter-web, dart-pub

Why do you use `onSubmitted:` option in `TextField()`,
I wanted to make Textfield than the option onsubmited came and i didnt understand anything changes in the final result , can anyone plz explain it to me that why we use onSubmitted option?

this is my code:

```
TextField(
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Password",
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                  width: 2,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  width: 2,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              ),
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.lock_outline,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `onSubmitted` property called when the user indicates that they are done editing the text in the field.

Simply when user press `Enter` on keyboard and while using `TextField`, it calls `onSubmitted`, it provides the `value` of that `TextField`. Suppose, we don't have any `TextEditingController` or using `onChanged` and we can use `setState` method to assign the value here. I only prefer it when I just concern about final value.

For More [onSubmitted](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onSubmitted.html)

Answer (score 0):

`onSubmitted` uses for when you press enter key, which triggers the callBack function(like print or other function).

```
TextField(
              onSubmitted: (value){
                print(value);
              },
            ),
```

For more [onSubmitted](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19027)

Answer (score 0):

It is used to pull the focus manually to another widget at the time when the user is done using the TextField (when the user presses enter).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).